# switch must be exhaustive in Recursive type

Tags: swift

```swift
enum Tree<Element: Comparable> {
  case empty
  indirect case node(Tree<Element>, Element, Tree<Element>)

  func forEach(withLooping fn: (Element) -> Void) {
    var stack = [self]
    while !stack.isEmpty {
      let current = stack.popLast()
      switch current {
      case .empty: break
      case let .node(left, value, right):
        fn(value)
        stack.append(left)
        stack.append(right)
      case .none: // !!!
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Xcode force me to add `.none` case, but `.none` is not a constructor of `Tree`

```
xxx.swift:9:7: error: switch must be exhaustive
      switch current {
      ^
xxx.swift:9:7: note: add missing case: '.none'
      switch current {
```

Why?

Comment: `popLast()` returns `Optional<Tree>`, and it has `.none` case.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is not that the enumeration is recursive, but that the [`popLast()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1539777-poplast) method returns an *optional* (which is `nil` if the array is empty). Therefore the possible case for `current` are

```
case .some(.empty):
case .some(.node(left, value, right)):
case .none: // Or equivalently: case nil:
```

As of Swift 5.1, enum cases can be matched against non-optional enum patterns (compare [SR-7799](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7799)) so that this simplifies to

```
case .empty:
case .node(left, value, right):
case .none: // Or equivalently: case nil:
```

This explains the compiler error and the fix-it.
However, the `nil` case cannot occur because you check that the array is not empty. Here are three possible solutions:

- Since you already checked that the stack is not empty you can force-unwrap safely

  ```
  while !stack.isEmpty {
    let current = stack.popLast()!
    switch current {
       // ...
  ```
- Use [`removeLast()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2885764-removelast) instead. This method *expects* that the array is not empty, and returns a (non-optional) array element:

  ```
  while !stack.isEmpty {
    let current = stack.removeLast()
    switch current {
       // ...
  ```
- Use `popLast()` with optional binding in the while-condition:

  ```
  while let current = stack.popLast() {
    switch current {
       // ...
  ```